# Is it possible to export 3D charts from MatPlotLib to TikZ?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, tikz

I am trying to export a 3D diagram from `Matplotlib` to `TikZ`, using `import tikzplotlib`. This is the code executed in `Jupyter NoteBook`:

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
z = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
x = z * np.sin(20 * z)
y = z * np.cos(20 * z)
ax.plot3D(x, y, z, 'gray')
ax.set_title('Intentando con 3D')
plt.show()

import tikzplotlib

tikzplotlib.save("papon.tex")
tikzplotlib.Flavors.latex.preamble()
```

The resulting `papon.tex` file shows the following when compiled:

```
% This file was created by tikzplotlib v0.9.8.
\begin{tikzpicture}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Missing any configuration or code modification? Or, simply, is it not possible to correctly export a 3D chart -with these characteristics- to `TikZ`?

Comment: I don't know anything about tikzplotlib, but does the pgf backend not work?

Comment: The graph is displayed correctly in `Matplotlib`. This is not the case when compiling the resulting .tex file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is *yes* to both questions.

The first problem is that you save the figure after `show`, which *consumes* the plot, and you save an empty new plot thereafter. The plot gets exported when you remove the following line:

```
plt.show()
```

**However**, the second problem is that 3d plots are indeed not supported. See [the tikzplotlib documentation](https://pypi.org/project/tikzplotlib/):

> Of course, not all figures produced by matplotlib can be converted
> without error. Notably, [3D plots don't work](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7243).

The output of your example above looks like the following, and the tikz output is a 2d plot. So there is no quick solution to turn that into the desired plot:

[image: Example output]